# Best way to run rake task every 2 min on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra, rake, sidekiq

I have a rails module that processes some active record objects, only about 15-20 at a time, that I need to start off every two minutes.

I have tried to offload it to sidekiq (and sidekiq-cron), which works, but with the concurrency, created many race conditions and duplicate data.

I really just need a simple rake task cron for rails or maybe sinatra (as I would create a new sinatra app just to complete these tasks)

- I either need to force sidekiq to process in a single thread or
- have a "cron" job run a rake task or even the module directly

  ```
  def self.process_events
    events = StripeEvent.where(processed: false)
    events = StripeServices.arrange_processing_order events
    events.each do |event_obj|
      StripeServices.new(event_obj).process_event_obj
    end
  end
  ```

thanks for any point in the right direction.

- edited

sorry I wasnt very clear. pushing my module to sidekiq caused concurrency issues that I wasnt ready for (my bit of code is not threadsafe), and with the restrictions that Heroku places on "crons", whats the best way to run a rake task every 2 min?

If Sinatra can do it, I would prefer it, but I cant find the solution for that same problem.

Comment: did you tried clockwork  https://github.com/adamwiggins/clockwork ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what are you asking. You already tried option 1, you can try option 2 (create the task and cron it, it's pritty easy) and you'll know better than anyone if it's better.

Anyway, I guess that both methods will have concurrency problems if one task takes more than 2 minutes.

You can add extra flags to prevent two task to process the same ServiceEvent (maybe add a boolean "processing" and set it to true when a task takes it).

Or maybe you can have a lock file to prevent a task to run if another one is already running (you create a file with a specific location and name when the task starts and delete it when it finishes processing, you can check if the file exists before starting a new task).

Comment: Thanks arieljuod, sorry I wasnt very clear.  pushing my module to sidekiq caused concurrency issues that I wasnt ready for, and with the restriction that Heroku places on "crons", whats the best way to run a rake task every 2 min?

Comment: I've never used Heroku so I didn't even know it has restrictions for crons hahaah, sorry. What are de corncurrency issues you are talking about? I gave you two techinques to prevent 2 diferent concurrent processes to process the same event, but "concurrency issues" is too ambiguous.